Angular second times api not show in Network tab/ chrome
I want to call GET api the first time it was called, but second times api not show in Network tab/ chrome. So I don't know whether angular interceptor block it?
receiptCardVoucherList(pageno:number,shift:any,day_shift:any,petro_id:number){
this.http.get(constDefault.API_URL+'/petros/receiptCardVoucherList/page:'+pageno+'/'+shift+'/'+day_shift+'/'+petro_id+'/'+this.login_year,{headers:this.headersdata}).subscribe(alldata => { console.log('https services site ',alldata)});
//if(alldata){
return this.http.get(constDefault.API_URL+'/petros/receiptCardVoucherList/page:'+pageno+'/'+shift+'/'+day_shift+'/'+petro_id+'/'+this.login_year,{headers:this.headersdata})
}
old data show but not call second time
